# Icon not showing in FloatingActionButton after changed programmatically

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-vectordrawable

I have an `AppCompatActivity` with a `TabLayout` and a `FloatingActionButton` that I change it's icons depending on which tab is currently displaying.

When I programmatically change the drawable of `FloatingActionButton` using `setImageDrawable` or `setImageResource`, the new icon does not show up, just the blank background of the button.

Strangely enough, if I hide and show the `FloatingActionButton` after I programmatically changed it's icon, it shows up.

This is the part where I change the icon:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout) {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            switch (position) {
                case 0: 
                    floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mMainActivity, R.drawable.ic_save_24dp));
                    if (!floatingActionButton.isShown()) floatingActionButton.show(); 
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mMainActivity, R.drawable.ic_add_24dp));
                    if (!floatingActionButton.isShown()) floatingActionButton.show(); 
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    floatingActionButton.hide(); 
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
                    break; 
            }
        }
    });
```

Before:

[image: before]

After I programmatically changed it to a "plus" vector drawable:

[image: result]

Expected:

[image: expected]

So, my question is: What is causing this, and how can it be solved?

Comment: Hmmm I'm having the same problem. I tried invalidate() but that didn't work. I'll update if I get it working. Did you make it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem and I solved by adding a call to the hide method

```
 mFloatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.default_fab_icon));
 mFloatingActionButton.hide();
 mFloatingActionButton.show();
```

I had tried `.invalidate()` but that did not work. This seems to be a problem when switching fragments. I experienced it whilst using the Navigation AndroidX components.

I don't think this is the best solution but I tried a lot and only this worked - there's no flickering effect.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117476935

Just upgrade to `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02` which fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks. The library upgrade (com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02) solved the problem for me.

Comment: I used to have `api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05' `. I had to downgrade to `api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'` and now it shows.